# product qty revert when paypal window closed in magento

Tags: magento

Here i am facing one issue. when create an order through paypal in magento after placing an order it is redirecting to paypal. here i am not paying amount just clicked on return to merchant site. in this case qty is reverting correctly to product. in this case order is showing in admin side as pending_payment status.

but forexample i am not clicking any button in paypal and not redirecting to merchant site and just close the window. in this time also order showing in backend as pending_payment status but not reverting qty to product.

anyone advise me what to do in this case.

thanks,
murali.

Answer (score 0):

we are just deleting this order after an half-hour.

Here is the code for delete pending_payment orders from orders grid. for this we set a cron job for delete paypal pending orders. if user close the paypal window it reverts the qty and delete that order. you can check it out here. copy code from below url and place it in magento root folder and set cron for delete pending orders :)

http://eightlessons.blogspot.in/2013/03/delete-pendingpayment-order-status-from.html